# Class 'App\Models\Student' not found when trying to acces model

Tags: php, laravel

i'm new to Laravel and i'm trying to use a model but i get this error, what could be?
Laravel Framework 8.34.0
PHP 7.4.3

I cant access this class App\Models\Student

Here's my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Student;


class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function createStudent(Request $request) {
        $student = new Student;
        $student->name = $request->name;
        $student->course = $request->course;
        $student->save();

        return response()->json([
          "message" => "student record created"
        ], 201);
      }

    
}
```

Ande Here's the model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'course'];
}
```

Comment: Wrong namespace? Where is the model located? Inside the `app/Models` folder? Then please correct its namespace and `use App\Models\Student`

Comment: If your file is in `app/Models/Student.php`, you need `App\Models\Student`. If it's in `app/Student.php`, you need `App\Student`. You've mixed the two in your question.

Comment: I still got the error, changed to `use App\Models\Student` and get the same error

Comment: What should be the correct namespace?

Comment: The "correct" namespace is up to you, but the namespace and the folder structure have to **match** correctly.

Comment: Thanks! The namespeace was worng, should be App/Models. I'm new to Laravel, so im understanding the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

Change in model

```
namespace App\Models;
```

Change in Controller

```
use App\Models\Student;
```

Also, try to run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

Lets Assume that you are using Laravel 8.Then you need to  add `use  App\Models\Student;`
to your Controller.
And change
`namespace App;`
To
`namespace App\Models;`

The `App\Models\Student`.  Is the location of your Student model ,which means the model Student should be inside Models folder inside the app folder of your laraval 8 project.
Make sure if the Student model is really existing...

If you are  another version (below laravel8) then the path will be `App\Student`

Comment: I still got the error, changed to use App\Models\Student and get the same error

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Okay then goto app->Models folder and look if there is a  File Named Student.php

Comment: Yes, i have Student.php and User.php (Default)

Comment: If Student is in App\Models folder, check your namespace. It's actually ```namespace App;``` and should be ```namespace App\Models;```

Comment: Thanks! The namespeace was worng, should be App/Models. I'm new to Laravel, so im understanding the basics.

Comment: You should always create Models with terminal to avoid this mistakes in future